# How to register member function to lua without lua bind in c++

Tags: c++, lua

I use lua 5.1 in my c++ game project, but I had a trouble to use lua when I try to register a c++ member function.
I want to use my c++ class member function in lua , but lua_register() function's 3rd
parameter can only accept c type normal function pointer or static member function's pointer.

I heard that lua bind library can solve this problem, but I do not want to use lua bind. It's good, but too heavy for my project.
Is there have any method to register c++ member function without any libraries?
How should I go about this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have gone through this same experience myself.

There are basically two good solutions that I know. One is good if the member function is for a class which there will only be one of, for each lua state. Another is more flexible but more complicated and slower. (I would be keen to learn other methods / improvements on these methods!)

I think lua_bind uses some templates quite similar to method 1, but uses tricks to make the implementation as flexible as method 2. I think either of these is more transparent than what lua_bind does.

### Method 1

(1) For each member function of `my_class` which you want to pass to lua, it should take `lua_State * L` and return `int`.

(2) At the time that lua is initialized, store a pointer to the associated `my_class` in the `lua_extraspace`.

```
*static_cast<my_class**>(lua_getextraspace(L_)) = &instance;
```

(3) When you want to pass member functions to lua, use a template like this:

```
typedef int (my_class::*mem_func)(lua_State * L);

// This template wraps a member function into a C-style "free" function compatible with lua.
template <mem_func func>
int dispatch(lua_State * L) {
    my_class * ptr = *static_cast<my_class**>(lua_getextraspace(L));
    return ((*ptr).*func)(L);
}
```

You then register things like this:

```
const luaL_Reg regs[] = {
    { "callback_1", &dispatch<&my_class::callback_1> },
    { "callback_2", &dispatch<&my_class::callback_2> },
    { "callback_3", &dispatch<&my_class::callback_3> },
    { NULL, NULL }
};
luaL_register(L, regs);
```

Method 1 has the benefit that it is pretty simple and extremely fast, I think it will be faster than lua bind. Because, `get_extraspace` doesn't do anything except a little pointer arithmetic. Most likely, a good compiler can optimize the `dispatch` template so that the function it makes is inlined, and there would be no overhead.

You may want to change the `dispatch` template so that there is a null pointer check at the extraspace, it depends on how the lifetimes of your lua state and your `my_class` are managed.

Potentially, you can also store more complicated stuff in the extraspace, like pointers to several different objects, or even like a vector or something (You can read about how to configure the lua extraspace in their docs). Or you could store things in the lua registry and the dispatch function can retrieve them from there, but the extraspace is faster -- it's up to you.

### Method 2

In method 2, you basically use the usual lua techniques for pushing a C++ object to lua that is owned by lua, but you do it where the object is a C++ `std::function` and you overload the `_call` metafunction so that it calls the function. (If you are not in C++11 you can use `boost::function`.)

Then when you want to push a c++ member function to lua, you use `std::bind` to make it a function object.

This method has the drawback that within lua, the type of the "function" will actually be `userdata`, but since you can call it just fine and use it as a function it doesn't really matter. If this is bad for you, one thing you can do is to use the same trick, but also afterwards, make a closure which has the function object userdata as an upvalue, and when the closure is called, it just forwards the arguments to the function object and returns the results. Then the type of the closure will be `function` in lua, but it will do basically the same thing.

```
typedef std::function<int(lua_State *)> lua_function;
char const * cpp_function = "CPP_Function";

static int intf_dispatcher ( lua_State* L )
{
    //make a temporary copy, in case lua_remove(L,1) might cause lua to garbage collect and destroy it
    lua_function f = * static_cast<lua_function *> (luaL_checkudata(L, 1, cpp_function));
    // remove from the stack before executing, so that like all other callbacks, f finds only its intended arguments on the stack.
    lua_remove(L,1);
    int result = (f)(L);
    return result;
}

static int intf_cleanup ( lua_State* L )
{
    lua_function * d = static_cast< lua_function *> (luaL_testudata(L, 1, cpp_function));
    if (d == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: intf_cleanup called on data of type: " << lua_typename( L, lua_type( L, 1 ) ) << std::endl;
        lua_pushstring(L, "C++ function object garbage collection failure");
        lua_error(L);
    } else {
        d->~lua_function();
    }
    return 0;
}

static int intf_tostring( lua_State* L )
{
    lua_function * d = static_cast< lua_function *> (luaL_checkudata(L, 1, cpp_function));
    // d is not null, if it was null then checkudata raised a lua error and a longjump was executed.
    std::stringstream result;
    result << "c++ function: " << std::hex << d;
    lua_pushstring(L, result.str().c_str());
    return 1;
}

void register_metatable ( lua_State* L )
{
    luaL_newmetatable(L, cpp_function);
    lua_pushcfunction(L, intf_dispatcher);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__call");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, intf_cleanup);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__gc");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, intf_tostring);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__tostring");
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1); //make a copy of this table, set it to be its own __index table
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");

    lua_pop(L, 1);
}

void push_function( lua_State* L, const lua_function & f )
{
    void * p = lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(lua_function));
    luaL_setmetatable(L, cpp_function);
    new (p) lua_function(f);
}
```

Comment: Method 1 works very nice, seems like `luaL_register` has been deprecated (in the header `lauxlib.h` it's only defined if `LUA_COMPAT_MODULE` is defined. What worked for me: `lua_register(L, "callback_1", &dispatch<&my_class::callback_1>);`

Comment: Is this trick still relevant ? I tried to use this hack, but I ended with the following error: ```error: no matches converting function ‘dispatch’ to type ‘lua_CFunction {aka int (*)(struct lua_State*)}’```. DId I forget or miss something ?

Comment: @accpnt hard to know without MCVE. my code is still compiling in 2020

Comment: Then I probably lack some basic C++ knowledge about templates

Comment: When you write "make a temporary copy", you only copy a pointer to the lua_function not the object itself, doesn't this mean that in case of garbage collection you will call the function on a destroyed object?

Comment: `lua_function f = * static_cast<lua_function *> (luaL_checkudata(...));` because we star the `lua_function *` that is the result of static cast, this line copies a function object of type `lua_function`

Answer (score -3):

The previous answer is correct.

In terms of the question, it depends if when you call the class member from lua, if you want lua to decide the object used, or you want to bind this to the member of a fixed object instance. If it is fixed, then it is rather trivial with std::bind to create a function object which holds the pointer to the member function to call, and the this pointer to call it with, and to register this with lua.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Code would look like this:

```
class C {
   public:
      void blah(lua_State* L);
};

C inst;

lua_pushcclosure(L, std::bind(&C::blah, &inst, std::placeholder::_1), 0);
lua_setglobal(L, "blah");
```

Also for a more natural way to bind C/C++ functions with lua that avoids writing wrappers, have a look here:

http://inspired-code.blogspot.com.au/p/automagical-language-bindings-using-c.html