# How do I use std::bind when registering a function in Lua?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, lua

In the question *How to register member function to lua without lua bind in c++* [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36104248/5300002) suggested the following code:

```
class C {
   public:
      void blah(lua_State* L);
};

C inst;

lua_pushcclosure(L, std::bind(&C::blah, &inst, std::placeholder::_1), 0);
lua_setglobal(L, "blah");
```

*(Quoted as it stood, including the small error in* `std::placeholders`*)*

However, I cuold not get that to work. The error message I got back states that the function returned by `std::bind` can't be converted to a `lua_CFunction`.

I have also tried changing the return type of `blah` to `int`, but I get the same error message. If it's helpful to anyone, the full error message is:

```
Error   C2664   'void lua_pushcclosure(lua_State *,lua_CFunction,int)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,int (__thiscall C::* )(lua_State *),C *,const std::_Ph<1> &>' to 'lua_CFunction'
```

I even tried to change `&C::blah` to `&inst.blah`, but that unsurprisingly didn't work either.

Has anyone gotten it to work? Or is it just not meant to work?

Comment: *I cuold not get that to work.* You are not supposed to. The referenced answer is plainly wrong.

Comment: should not your function have a signature of `int blah(lua_State* L)`

Comment: Yes @macroland, you're right. I have tried that as well, though, and still no luck.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636373/how-stdbind-works-with-member-functions

Comment: Thank you @macroland - that was very informative and helped me understand `std::bind` better. However, I'm still puzzled as to whether that means `std::bind` cannot be used with `lua_pushcclosure` or whether there is a way around it?

Comment: Frankly, I havent tried `std::bind` to glue C++ and Lua. Why not add C and C++ to your tags to be able to get some more opinions.

Comment: @JanHudec thank you for your reply! However, I don't really understand what I need to do. Would you mind giving more information or even an example? Maybe even as an answer to the question?

Comment: @JanHudec no need to be so rude! You claim that "`std::bind` _could_ be used to create a lua closure" so excuse me if I mistook that for you actually knowing anything about the subject. Clearly you miss the point of my question - the reply I'm referencing (**and you**, in your comment) claims that `std::bind` can be used - my question is, _is that correct or false and if it's correct, then how do I get it to work_?
Your comment is utterly unhelpful.

Comment: @kim, ok **comment deleted**.

Comment: You can't. Lua expects a C function. You're handing it an object with an overloaded operator `()`. Huge difference.